# Electrical machine(s)

Tags: induction-motor

I understand that when the torque is produced in the rotor, it tends to rotate the rotor in the same direction as that of rotation of field, but my concern is that when is the torque produced in the motor?

Comment: When there is a current supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Torque is produced by the moving magnetic field interacting with magnets or eddy currents in the rotor.

Comment: it doesnt have to be moving

Comment: true, it only only needs to be moving relative to the rotor for induction machines, for permanent magnet machines it's stationary relative to the rotor.

Answer (score 0):

Torque is produced, when field is created but rotor will not start rotating instantaneously because, rotor inertia will be greater than the torque at the start.Rotor will start rotating when torque is greater than inertia of rotor.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Lee.

Maybe you could watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQqyGNOP_3o) from [Learn Engineering](http://i.youku.com/LearnEngineeringCN). It gives a nice animated 3D view of what happens in an induction motor.